# Jump from one tag content to next tag content in Sublime

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, key-bindings

Currently I have to edit a lot of HTML content and therefore I was wondering if there is a `Sublime`  key shortcut to move from one tag content to the next.

For example I have a huge list and edited the content of an `li`. To go to the next `li` content and 'highlight' it for edit I need to use the mouse or a lot of the arrow keyboard keys.

I hope you understand what I describe. I'm not really sure how to 'phrase' this issue, therefore I was not very successful using Google.

As Sublime is generally awesome I was wondering if there is a shortcut for this.

I'm using `Sublime Text 3` on `Windows`. But `Mac` key shortcuts are also ok, since I use Sublime on my MacBook as well. Or just telling me the name of the respective Key Binding, so I can set it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not do exactly what you're asking for, but should allow you to spend quite a lot less keystrokes/mouse click.

If the cursor is placed after an opening angle bracket `<`, you can use the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select *the content of the enclosing tag* e.g. with the cursor anywhere on line two after the first `<`:

```
<div>
  <p>This is content...</p>
</div>
```

Would select the text: `This is content...`.

You would still have to do moving to next tag yourself.

Comment: Thx, this is already a very good start to saving time/effort.